# How to open multi project on the WebStorm IDE by JetBrains

Tags: webstorm

I want to open multi project on WebStorm IDE version 2019.3.1 by JetBrains what the same with IntelliJ IDE.

[image]

Anyone can help me, thanks all

Answer (score 1):

They can be configured in `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Project Opening`.

If you choose `Confirm window to open project in`, you can choose at each time you open the project

Comment: +1. Official help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/opening-reopening-and-closing-projects.html#ws_opening_multiple_projects